# JSSOR my slider is too small in small resolution

Tags: slider, responsive, jssor

My problem is in the title.
My slider is responsive but nothing can be read correctly in small resolution.
For the moment I put it inside a test page of my website:
https://www.assistante-34.com/test.html
You will find the code inside my page.

```html
<!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->
<!-- Generator: Jssor Slider Maker -->
<script src="/jssor/jssor.slider-27.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:1000,x:-1,y:2,$Rows:2,$Zoom:11,$Rotate:1,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:2049,$ChessMode:{$Row:15},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Top:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear,$Rotate:$Jease$.$InExpo},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Rotate:0.85}},
          {$Duration:1000,$Zoom:11,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Zoom:$Jease$.$InExpo,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: 1,
          $SlideDuration: 900,
          $FillMode: 1,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
          },
          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,
            $SpacingX: 2,
            $SpacingY: 2
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        /*#region responsive code begin*/

        var MAX_WIDTH = 3000;

        function ScaleSlider() {
            var containerElement = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode;
            var containerWidth = containerElement.clientWidth;

            if (containerWidth) {

                var expectedWidth = Math.min(MAX_WIDTH || containerWidth, containerWidth);

                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(expectedWidth);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }

        ScaleSlider();

        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        /*#endregion responsive code end*/
    };
</script>
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100italic,300,300italic,regular,italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=latin-ext,greek-ext,cyrillic-ext,greek,vietnamese,latin,cyrillic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
    .jssorl-004-double-tail-spin img{animation-name:jssorl-004-double-tail-spin;animation-duration:1.6s;animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-timing-function:linear}@keyframes jssorl-004-double-tail-spin{from{transform:rotate(0);}to{transform:rotate(360deg);}}.jssorb032{position:absolute}.jssorb032 .i{position:absolute;cursor:pointer}.jssorb032 .i .b{fill:#fff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000;stroke-width:1200;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:.25}.jssorb032 .i:hover .b{fill:#bfce00;fill-opacity:.6;stroke:#fff;stroke-opacity:.35}.jssorb032 .iav .b{fill:#000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#fff;stroke-opacity:.35}.jssorb032 .i.idn{opacity:.3}
</style>
<div id="jssor_1" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:1300px;height:339px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" class="jssorl-004-double-tail-spin" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
        <img style="margin-top:-19px;position:relative;top:50%;width:38px;height:38px;" src="/jssor/everlia2/double-tail-spin.svg" />
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:1300px;height:339px;overflow:hidden;">
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="/jssor/everlia2/maison-container-equitable.jpg" />
            <div style="position:absolute;top:9px;left:84px;width:663px;height:102px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:50px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1;text-align:left;text-shadow:0px 0px 4px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);">
                <div>La construction équitable,</div>
                <div>nouvelle génération</div>
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:9px;left:84px;width:637px;height:107px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:50px;color:#050505;line-height:1;text-align:left;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);">
                <div>La construction équitable,</div>
                <div>nouvelle génération</div>
            </div>
            <a href="http://www.everlia.com" style="display:block; position:absolute;top:127px;left:87px;width:84px;height:26px;max-width:84px;">
                <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" border="0" src="/jssor/everlia2/bouton2.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="/jssor/everlia2/maison-container-evolutive.jpg" />
            <div style="position:absolute;top:9px;left:84px;width:897px;height:114px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:50px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1;text-align:left;text-shadow:0px 0px 4px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);">
                <div>Construction évolutive,</div>
                <div>create your fashion design<br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:9px;left:84px;width:870px;height:112px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:50px;color:#050505;line-height:1;text-align:left;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);">
                <div>Construction évolutive,</div>create your fashion design
            </div>
            <a href="http://www.everlia.com" style="display:block; position:absolute;top:129px;left:88px;width:84px;height:26px;max-width:84px;">
                <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" border="0" src="/jssor/everlia2/bouton2.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="/jssor/everlia2/maisoncontainerclimatique.jpg" />
            <div style="position:absolute;top:9px;left:84px;width:962px;height:117px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:50px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1;text-align:left;text-shadow:0px 0px 4px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);">
                <div>Une construction climatique<br />et écologique<br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:9px;left:84px;width:943px;height:154px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:50px;color:#050505;line-height:1;text-align:left;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);">
                <div>Une construction climatique</div>
                <div>et écologique<br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="http://www.everlia.com" style="display:block; position:absolute;top:129px;left:89px;width:84px;height:26px;max-width:84px;">
                <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" border="0" src="/jssor/everlia2/bouton2.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="/jssor/everlia2/maison-container-rapide.jpg" />
            <div style="position:absolute;top:9px;left:84px;width:1093px;height:147px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:50px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1;text-align:left;text-shadow:0px 0px 4px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);">
                <div>Construction rapide, économique</div>
                <div>et performante<br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:9px;left:84px;width:1090px;height:107px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:50px;color:#050505;line-height:1;text-align:left;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);">
                <div>Construction rapide, économique</div>
                <div>et performante<br />
                </div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <a href="http://www.everlia.com" style="display:block; position:absolute;top:129px;left:86px;width:84px;height:26px;max-width:84px;">
                <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" border="0" src="/jssor/everlia2/bouton2.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u="image" src="/jssor/everlia2/maison-container-techno.jpg" />
            <div style="position:absolute;top:9px;left:84px;width:1043px;height:153px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:50px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1;text-align:left;text-shadow:0px 0px 4px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);">
                <div>Construction container haute</div>
                <div>technologie</div>
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:9px;left:84px;width:1059px;height:155px;font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;font-size:50px;color:#050505;line-height:1;text-align:left;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);">
                <div>Construction container haute</div>
                <div>technologie</div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <a href="http://www.everlia.com" style="display:block; position:absolute;top:129px;left:88px;width:84px;height:26px;max-width:84px;">
                <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" border="0" src="/jssor/everlia2/bouton2.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
    <style>
/* swiper slide*/

.jssorb032 {position: absolute;}
.jssorb032 .i {position:absolute;cursor:pointer;fill:#fff;fill-opacity:1;} 
.jssorb032 .1 .b {fill:#bfce00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#fff;}
.jssorb032 .i:hover .b {fill: #bfce00;}
.jssorb032 .iav .b {fill:#bfce00;}
</style>
    <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb032" style="position:absolute;bottom:12px;right:12px;data-scale="0.5" data-scale-bottom="0.75">
        <div data-u="prototype" class="i" style="width:15px;height:15px;">
            <svg viewbox="0 0 16000 16000" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
                <circle class="b" cx="8000" cy="8000" r="5800"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">jssor_1_slider_init();</script>
<!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->
```

May be I do a mistake.
Thank you for your help.

Regards,
Danielle F.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the logic is correct, layers will scale along with the slider.

You can fix it in one of two ways,

1. Make the layer larger with larger font size.
2. Specify a class name (e.g. **yourlayer**) of the layer, write manual media query css code to control the display size of the layer on various resolutions.

   `<style>
       @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
           .yourlayer {
               font-size: 50px !important;
           }
       }
       @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
           .yourlayer {
               font-size: 80px !important;
           }
       }
       @media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
           .yourlayer {
               font-size: 200px !important;
           }
       }
   </style>`

[image]

Comment: Hi,Thank you very much for your answer. I try and come back to you if I have any further question. Regards. Danielle F.

Comment: Have your tried on mobile device? Any url that I can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

May be I don't understand where I have to change "layer larger with larger font size". I made several tests and if I change something in my slider: 
1/ a scroll bar appears in the bottom of the slider 
2/ pictures are too large 
3/ the button/link is under main text 
Furthermore, bullets keeps their small size.

See in my website https://www.assistante-34.com/test.html. 
I also precise to you that I'm obliged to add this in the properties of my page so my slider is in full width:

```html
<style>

#imPageRowContent_2,
#imPageRow_2 div[id^="imCell"] {
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%!important;
 height: 100%!important;
}
</style>
```

Thank your for your enlightened help. I'm not used to using code you know. Regards.
Danielle

Comment: As the font-size has already specified with inline style, add `!important` in css then. Please see edited answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to discover today that my request was deleted. I'm very happy for your help, really (no critique only SOS)... I just wanted to precise that with the new test, the text appears very big in large width 1920 .... I also asked the question if to remedy the problem I could not specify the size of the font in vw and not in px ... Many thanks for your help. Regards, Danielle

Comment: Hi, I didn't received your help since last 24th Oct. I don't understand where is my problem with font size for small width. Thank you by advance. Danielle Fabre